# onclick of image double tap zoom using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to provide zoom effects on double tap of an image in mobile screens for an ecommerce website. Can any one suggest me how to do that ?

Comment: Did you try to use Google?

Comment: yes. But, i didn't get proper result

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Make an attempt at creating this yourself and then if you run into any problems there will be a good chance that someone here wants and can help you.

Comment: You want us to code it for you? You don't show us what error you have tried to solve or make this yourself, please include all relevant code.

Comment: I didn't mean that you have to code for my query, i am just asking suggestions where can i get the solution.